# DropDownList RequiredFieldValidator is not working

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a DropDownList in my asp.net web page.
The RequiredFieldValidator is not working. Thanks for looking at my code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Organization" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="OrganizationList"
    DataTextField="OrgName" DataValueField="OrgCode" CausesValidation="True">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="OrganizationList" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MembershipDB %>"
    SelectCommand="Admin_GetOrganizationDropDown" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidatorOrg"
    ControlToValidate="Organization"
    ErrorMessage="Organization is required." 
    Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: SO should disallow questions with expressions like "not working".

Comment: Does the `Organization` dropdown have a blank value for default, such as `select one...`, or does it show the first choice as default?

Comment: Why? Tim. I don't understand.

Comment: Because "not working" tells absolutely nothing about the expected behavior or what is going wrong.

Comment: @mellamokb, the answer is no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have not allready done it you should have a value that means that you are not selecting anything. Like this:

```
 Organization.Insert(0,new ListItem("--Select--","0"));
```

And then you need to tell the `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` to check for a value that you are not allowing. So InitialValue value should be 0. Like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0"
```

Then when the `--Select--` option is chosen and you try to submit the page. The `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` will fire.

**Edit**

I don't like the look of the bit of sql you are showing:

```
Select Distinct 
    'name' As [OrgCode],'Please Select' As [OrgName] 
FROM [MedOrganization] 
Union All 
SELECT [OrgCode], [OrgName] FROM [MedOrganization]
```

Not a performance vise good piece of sql code. You can do this instead:

```
Select
    'name' As [OrgCode],'Please Select' As [OrgName] 
Union All 
SELECT [OrgCode], [OrgName] FROM [MedOrganization]
```

Why use the `distinct` there? When you can just select like above. Back to the question. You can try having the `InitialValue` set to `name` like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="name"
```

Comment: My stored procedure is Select Distinct 'name' As [OrgCode],'Please Select' As [OrgName] FROM [MedOrganization] Union All
                                SELECT [OrgCode], [OrgName] FROM [MedOrganization]. Thus it has a default value.

Answer (score 0):

The below works without forcing a *Select/Please Select* into clean organization only collection:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrganization" runat="server" CssClass="sel_box" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvOrganization" ControlToValidate="ddlOrganization" InitialValue="" ValidationGroup="vgOrganization" runat="server" Display="None" meta:resourceKey="rfvOrganization" />
```

Not `InitialValue=""`.

HTH.